# LinkedList add new node based on priority number

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, adt

my java data structure assignment requirements are to create a food management to assign the food to the victim of the natural disaster and it also requires to handle 3 types of victim which are child, oldFolks and adult.

What I wanted to achieve is say I have a LinkedList to arrange the priorities. So now I have a `Person` object that downcast to `Victim` and `Patient`. I need to handle the victim.

**Victim object**

- `setPriority` (here I categories the victim into priority 1,2,3 which are `child`, `oldfolks` and `adults` based on their DOB)

So now I will have a victim object and priority of it.

My idea is in the linkedlist ADT, I divides it into 3 portions which is first `child`, 2nd is `oldfolks` and 3rd is `adults`.

[image]

Above is a picture of my idea, when adding a new victim and the priority is 2, I need to get the last old folk and then put the new victim at the back and then increment the `lastOldFolk` location.

Below is what I have done so far:-

```
public boolean addByPriority(T newEntry, int priority) {
        Node newNode = new Node(newEntry);
        System.out.println(firstNode);

        if (firstNode == null) {//if empty list then straight away assign
            firstNode = newNode;
            switch (priority) {//update the last location of each priorities
                case 1:
                    lastChild++;
                    lastSenior++;
                    lastAdult++;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    lastSenior++;
                    lastAdult++;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    lastAdult++;
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        } else if (firstNode != null && priority == 1) {//if priority is 1 then add here
            Node node = firstNode;
            for (int i = 0; i < lastChild; i++) {
                node = node.next;
            }
            Node savedNext = node.next;
            node.next = newNode;
            node.next.next = savedNext;
            lastChild++;
        } else if (firstNode != null && priority == 2) {
        } else {
        }
        length++;
        return true;
    }
```

So now at my main program, I added 3 of each priorities after that I add another `newEntry` with priority 1, it will store at 4th position of priority 1 but doesn't work if I add another new priority 1. I am new to data structure, I hope someone can enlighten me.

P/S: I'm not allowed to use arraylist or any Java API to complete the task, I have to create my own ADT to the solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: did you check my solution ?

Comment: @RanKoretzki I just reached home from dinner. I trying it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your scaning the list and not directly accessing the placement location,
there is no need to keep track on last of <> each type.

you can do a simple while loop, until you reach a node who priority, is lower
than the new node or null, that is when you should add the new node.
if the list is null, just put the new node.

```
if (firstNode == null) {//if empty list then straight away assign
     firstNode = newNode;
} else {
     if (newNode.getPriority() < firstNode.getPriority()) {
          newNode.next = firstNode;
          firstNode = newNode;
     } else {
         Node current = firstNode;
         while (current.getNext() != null && newNode.getPriority() >= current.getNext().getPriority()) 
             current = current.getNext();
         } 
         newNode.setNext(current.getNext());
         current.setNext(newNode); 
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am creating generic data type ADT and the `getPriority()` method is from a subclass `Person` which is `Victim` and I will determine the priority of the `Victim` before passing into the ADT that was shown at my question `public boolean addByPriority(T newEntry, int priority)`. Thanks.

Comment: I have tried your code, it's working but it is arranged the wrong direction. Priority 1 is top priority then  priority 2 and priority 3. I randomly added 4 entries say priority 1, priority 2, priority 3 and priority 2 and the result wasn't p1,p2,p2,p3 but p3,p2,p2,p1. Can you help me?

Comment: fixed it in the if condition. check now.

Comment: I got incorrect result: p3,p2,p1,p2. There is one more situation we need to consider which is when p3 is in the linkedlist, and new entry is a p2, we have to add it in front of p3 so the result will we p2,p3 so on and so forth. Thanks.

Comment: forgat to change first condition. now fixed.
please try.

Comment: Yes, thank you friend. You saved me from extra hours of headache! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution seems unnecessarily complicated; what I would do is just create a class, say Line, which holds the 3 independent lists. Something like this:

```
class Line {
    private ArrayList<Victim> children;
    private ArrayList<Victim> oldFolks;
    private ArrayList<Victim> adults;

    public void addByPriority(Victim newEntry, int priority) {
        switch(priority) {
        case 1:
             children.add(newEntry);
        break;
        case 2:
             oldFolks.add(newEntry);
        break;
        case 3:
             adults.add(newEntry);
        break;
    }

    public void nextPatient() {
        if(!children.isEmpty()) return children.remove(0);
        if(!oldFolks.isEmpty()) return oldFolks.remove(0);
        if(!adults.isEmpty()) return adults.remove(0);
        return null; // or throw exception, as you like
    }
}
```

Here I used ArrayList, but there is for sure some other java library implementation of a stack (like [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html)), which is more suited for the purpose.

You could even make the Line class implement the [list interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) so that you can still use it as any other standard list (you will need to override the methods though, to take into account the 3 queues)

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution but I forgot to mention, I'm not allowed to use arraylist or any Java API, I have to create myself.

Comment: the idea still applies, if you like it, just replace ArrayList with your own Stack class, which internally uses a simple normal array... which is more or less what ArrayList does (except for the memory management as the list grows)

Comment: Okay noted, I will try to do it your way. Thanks!